# why does ta.valuewhen jump back to a previous occurrence in pine script v5?

Tags: pine-script

```
been trying to solve this since weeks:
why does the KSSP_Low value change back to an older occurrence a few bars after KuverSellSavePlot  happened???
KuverSellPlot also changes back to previous value after 2 bars, that,s why i used the array, but it does not help either ... but the associated plot remains correctly.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
KuverSellSave = 0.0
if KuverSellPlot
    array.push(KuverPlotSave, KuverSellPlot)
    KuverSellSave := -1
    KuverSellSave
    
KuverSellSavePlot = KuverSellSave == -1 
//
KSSP_Low    = ta.valuewhen(KuverSellSavePlot, low, 0)
```

as said above i even tried to save the value in an array but that also goes back to the previous value ... and i read everything that could find on the topic but have not seen this question discussed anywhere so far ... i recorded a short video to xplain it, too, but i guess it,s not allowed to share youtube links here?

```
KuverSellSave = 0.0
if KuverSellPlot
    array.push(KuverPlotSave, KuverSellPlot)
    KuverSellSave := -1
    KuverSellSave
    
KuverSellSavePlot = KuverSellSave == -1 
//
KSSP_Low    = ta.valuewhen(KuverSellSavePlot, low, 0)
```

Comment: How do you calculate `KuverSellPlot` ?

Comment: You should give us a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thx guys, i inserted my code into a different strategy template and the error did not appear there, so let,s consider this case closed for now.